# Rails system test generator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, system-testing

I was going through this article [A Guide to Testing Rails Applications](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#system-testing) and I was trying to implement System Tests for some of the models.

But on running the generator `bin/rails generate system_test articles` in the guide, I come across the following error:

`Running via Spring preloader in process 16461
Expected string default value for '--helper'; got true (boolean)
Expected string default value for '--assets'; got true (boolean)
Could not find generator 'system_test'. Maybe you meant 'assets', 'scss:assets' or 'js:assets'
Run 'rails generate --help' for more options.`

I installed capybara but I can't figure out how to get this to work.

Any clue on how to get this to work? Thanks in advance :)

edit: I'm running rails 5.0.1

Comment: What's your rails version? I'm pretty sure you need 5.1 for this to work.

Comment: running rails 5.0.1

Answer (score 1):

This feature is available in Rails 5.1, and not the version I'm running (5.0.1).